# Cannot run redmine 1.1 in a tomcat container

Tags: tomcat, redmine, warbler

this is my absolutely first time I get involved with Ruby & Co... so maybe I'm totally wrong.. excuse me in advance :-)

Anyway my problem is: I've installed redmine 1.1 and have followed the instructions here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Apache_Tomcat

Everything seems fine (all steps are OK, included running ./scripts/server -e production ), but when I put the redmine-1.1.war into the Tomcat webapps folder and I try to access from the browser (ie: http://localhost:8080/redmine-1.1 I just see:

Internal error

An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your redMine administrator for assistance.

*BUT* If I give a look to my catalina.out, I can see only few warnings;

So, maybe it's a trivial problem, but I don't know how to make the log more verbose..

This is my catalina.out dump:

INFO: Server startup in 27337 ms
config.gem: Unpacked gem rubytree-0.5.2 in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
config.gem: Unpacked gem coderay-0.9.7 in vendor/gems has no specification file. Run 'rake gems:refresh_specs' to fix this.
/usr/share/tomcatProduzione/webapps/redmine-1.1/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement

This is my configuration:

Tomcat 6.0.29

Ruby 1.8.7.302, ruby-gems is 1.3.5:

This is my list of installed gems:

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0145.2)
i18n (0.4.2)
jruby-jars (1.5.6)
jruby-openssl (0.7.3)
jruby-rack (1.0.7)
pg (0.10.1)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
warbler (1.2.1)

Comment: JRuby (and thus Tomcat) is not officially supported for Redmine, there are known bugs and afaik, the Redmine devs are not actively trying to get it running on JRuby. Your are probably going to face some issues along the way. That said, https://github.com/finnlabs/redmine_warbler might help you.

Comment: thanks, I try with the link you've provided...

Comment: I also have a version of Redmine configured to use Bundler at https://github.com/nicksieger/redmine. Check it out, run `bundle install` followed by `warble`. Also, don't forget to `rake db:migrate` or `rake redmine:load_default_data`!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this earlier in 2011, to set up a code-repository-aware Wiki for work (We're a Java team, so getting access to Tomcat was easy, root server access 'not so').

I couldn't get it working at the time, so the team settled on JamWiki from a documentation point of view (it can't connect to our code repositories). Anyway, I wanted to get Redmine 1.1 running, I had some measure of success with the stuff I'm posting here, not used it for a while though, being that we've got JamWiki.

See how you get on, hopefully, this will get you some mileage:

```
#/bin/sh

jgem install rack --version "=1.0.1"
jgem install hoe --version ">=2.8.8"
jgem install jruby-jars --version "=1.5.6"
jgem install jruby-openssl activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
jgem install warbler --version "=1.2.1"
jgem install -v=0.4.2 i18n

#Rails was  2.3.5
jgem install -v=2.3.11 rails

jruby -S rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
jruby -S rake redmine:load_default_data RAILS_ENV=production

#jruby -S rake generate_session_store
jruby -S rake config/initializers/session_store.rb

jruby -S  warble war

#For safe keeping - hinted on during my investigation
#jruby -S rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
#rake config/initializers/session_store.rb
#rake generate_session_store
```

Also, here is a pointer to configure a pure Java database (useful for testing etc). I haven't tried this, however:

```
#../redmine1.1/config/
#├── database.yml

development:
    adapter: jdbch2
    #WHERE REQUIRED.... #
    #database: db/sds_h2_database
    #username: #####
    #password: #####
    #jndi: ####
    #etc, etc

test:
    adapter: jdbch2 
    #WHERE REQUIRED.... #
    #database: db/sds_h2__test_database

production:
    adapter: jdbch2 
    #WHERE REQUIRED.... #
    #database: db/sds_h2_database
```

See also: 
http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/ActiveRecord-JDBC
https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter

Please let us know how you get on

Cheers

Rich